# Using jQuery ajax in Jquery DataTables for Asp.net WebForms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, initialization, datatables

Can I use a function instead of link to a textFile in ajax part of jQuery DataTables ? because it returns correct data, but nothing is shown in table: 
Here is my code:

```
  function Initialize() {

            $('#Items').dataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                ajax: createAjax(),
                columns: [
                    { data: "CatNum" },
                    { data: "CId" },
                    { data: "Advertiser" },
                    {
                        data: {
                            _: "StartTimeDisplay",
                            sort: "StartTime"
                        }
                    },
                    { data: "ContactID" },
                    { data: "AdvertiserID" }
                ]
            });
        }


    function createAjax() {
            var param = { ID: $("#<%=hfID.ClientID %>").val() };
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "WebSource.aspx/GetCompanies",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               data: JSON.stringify(param),
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (response) {
                    return JSON.stringify(response.d);
                },
                failure: function (response) { return response.d }
            });
        }
```

This is the part I mentioned about :
**ajax: createAjax()**

Comment: Is this working for you? If its working then definitely you can use..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao its not working. the JSON string created correctly,(I  loged it in console) , but when I use it as a parameter for Datatable, its not done right, and still no Error.

Comment: Why don't you try directly keeping `$.ajax` in `ajax:` option?

Comment: Didn't catch what you mean? Do you mean just putting function in ajax:?

Comment: Something like this `"ajax": {
            "url": "data/objects_root_array.txt",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },` from this **[source](https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html)**. Even though `.txt` is the source there you can return as proper json object from calling method..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I prefer not to use .txt as **ajax:** part , If I can.

Comment: I think you need to use **[serverside](https://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)** option for this..

Comment: There they have used `.php` as `ajax url` and you can call you method instead..